# Stop pandas dataframe from converting to vector

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have below `pandas dataframe`

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'product name': ['laptop', 'printer', 'printer',], 'price': [1200, 150, 1200],  'price1': [1200, 150, 1200]})
```

Now I want to print one single row

```
df.iloc[1,:]
```

This gives below result

```
product name    printer
price               150
price1              150
Name: 1, dtype: object
```

As can be seen here, above display is a column format. Is it possible to preserve the row format of original `dataframe` when displaying a single row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, `df.iloc[1,:]` is not a `pd.DataFrame` it is a `pd.Series` you can check it with `type(df.iloc[1, :])`. So row or column doesn't have any sense in these case.

To keep it as a `pd.DataFrame` you could select a range of rows of length 1: `df.iloc[1:2, :]` or `df.iloc[[1], :]`